# SAS proc mixed model: NO difference observed when changing the variable in the left side of the model

Tags: sas

I run a mixed model according to the PROC MIXED step in SAS. My code is like this below:

```
proc mixed data=inds;
   class subject arm(ref='C') ;
   model aval =base arm avisitn arm*avisitn /s ;
   random subject ;
   repeated /  subject=subject ;
   lsmeans arm / diff cl at avisitn=0;
   lsmeans arm / diff cl at avisitn=1;
   lsmeans arm / diff cl at avisitn=2;
   ods output  diffs=diff ;
run;
```

Then I change the variable in the model option at the left side of the equation like this:

```
proc mixed data=inds;
   class subject arm(ref='C') ;
   model chg =base arm avisitn arm*avisitn /s;
   random subject ;
   repeated / subject=subject ;
/*   lsmeans arm / pdiff cl at avisitn=0;*/
   lsmeans arm / pdiff cl at avisitn=1;
   lsmeans arm / pdiff cl at avisitn=2;
   ods output  diffs=diff1 ;
run;
```

I just change the variable from the value at each time point to the change from baseline.
Then I find that the **Differences of Least Squares Means** is the same.
I do not know how this works.
Can anyone tell me why?

A explanation from the model and a suggestion from the code so that I can see why I get the same results.

Comment: Maybe related to the equation: `CHG=AVAL-BASE`

Comment: I think you are right.
In the first formula, it is `(Mean of AVAL at level 1) – (Mean of AVAL at level 2)`.
In the second formula, it is `((Mean of AVAL at level 1) – baseline) – ((Mean of AVAL at level 2) – baseline)`.
So the baseline has been subtracted.
I think this is the right explanation. What do you say?

Comment: I am not good at theory... If I were you, I would do more programming test to verify this speculation.